# JQUERY onchange() get selected option and pass to variable to be inserted into Mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm attempting to get the selected value from a drop-menu down menu, create a value as a variable depending on the selection and insert the value of the variable into a MYSQL table.

Here's my current code:

**HTML / PHP**

```
<select id="customer_country" name="customer_country"
class="validate[required] input_styling target"
style="background: #FFFFFF;">
                <option value="">Please Select a Country</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                <option value="Andorra" selected>Andorra</option>
...

</select>

<?PHP 

$shipping = */ post javascript variable here */

$sql = mysql_query('UPDATE orders
SET shipping=$shipping
WHERE order_id='$r[order_id']');

?>

<div class="overlay-bg">
      <div class="overlay-content">
          <p>You have selected a country of residence outside of the United Kingdom.</p>
          <p>Please note we only accept credit card payments from UK customers.</p>
          <p>If you are a customer from outside the UK, please click the
          Paypal icon to be taken through to Paypal checkout to complete your order.</p>
          <td width="185" align="center" valign="middle">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
            <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$r['order_title_1']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$r['order_title_2']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$r['order_title_3']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="<?=$shipping?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$r['order_total']?>" />
            <input type="image" src=""
                   name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" />
            </form>
          <p>However, if you are a UK customer and simply made an error,
          please click below to return to the checkout page.</p>
          <p>Thank you</p>
          <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // show popup when selecting a country from the drop-down
    $( ".target" ).change(function() {
     if($(this).val() != "United Kingdom") {
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
        $('.overlay-bg').show().css({'height' : docHeight}); 
        $('.overlay-content').css({'top': scrollTop+20+'px'});
     }
    });
```

The code would do the following:

- Get the value of the option selected
- If the option isn't UK - one of the two conditions below would be applied

**Condition 1**

If the option selected was Albania, Algeria, Afghanistan -
 a variable would be created with the value of £15.00

**Condition 2**

If the option selected was American Samoa, Aland Islands -
 a variable would be created with the value of £10.00

- This value would then be entered into the MYSQL table with an UPDATE statement based on the given `order_id`.

**EDIT**

Would it be possible to echo the javascript value to then be stored by the server as a PHP variable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is dropdown created dynamicaly

Comment: @Bala - it's a static list

Comment: What exactly is the issue here ?

Comment: @dreamweiver - It's all laid out in my question above. What specifically are you querying?

Comment: You can use the attribute selector for retrieve the selected value. After this, just create your var with your values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the price in `data attribute` based on that you can get the money of countery

### HTML

```
<select id="customer_country" name="customer_country" class="validate[required] input_styling target" style="background: #FFFFFF;">
    <option value="" data-price="0">Please Select a Country</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan" data-price="15">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Åland Islands" data-price="10">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania" data-price="15">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria" data-price="15">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa" data-price="10">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Andorra" data-price="0" selected>Andorra</option>
</select>
```

### JS

```
var money = 0;
$(".target").change(function () {
  // this.value; to get the selected country value
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    money = optionSelected.data("price");
    alert(money);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HuKab/32/)

Comment: Thanks - how could I post this to the server to be posted and stored as a PHP variable, rather than displaying it as an alert?

Comment: sorry i don t know any sever side language

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** this is not a full answer as you did not provide enough information to even give one. i'm proposing a few fixes to your javascript and also a way to do the checks for different countries.

```
$(function() { // function in closure - should be where you instantiate event listeners
    // show popup when selecting a country from the drop-down
    $(".target").on('change', function() { // correct / updated syntax for 'change' function
        //finding the selected one...
        var opt = $(this).find(':selected').text(), // finds the selected options text
        money = 0;
        switch(opt){ // simple switch on the option where you set money
            case "Albania":
            case "Algeria":
            case "Afghanistan":
                money = 15.00;
                break;
            case "American Samoa":
            case "Aland Islands":
                money = 10.00
                break;
            case "United Kingdom":
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** decided to write more :)

**SEND THE DATA:**

you need to make an ajax request to send the data back to the server side where you can run your INSERT. pass money as the parameter.

you could try something like this:

```
$.post('whatever-file-name.php', {
    moneySent: JSON.stringify(money)}, function(res){
        alert(res);
    });
```

**INSERT THE DATA:**

I'm no php expert so this may or may not be completely correct.

something like this: pulled from [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO some-table (id, order_id, money)
VALUES ('1', ?? ,".$_POST['moneySent'].")");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**ISSUES:**
There is no order_id here that I can see.